# Area of the region traced by the envelope of a line segment

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, locus

Let $C$ be a variable point in the first quadrant on line $x+y=1$, which intersects the axes at $A$ and $B$ respectively. Let $D$ and $E$ be the foot of perpendiculars on the axes from the point $C$, And $P(h,k)$ be a point on the line segment $DE$.

We need to find

1.the maximum possible value of product $hk$.

2.the area traced by point $P$.

I assumed a point $C(\cos^2\theta,\sin^2\theta)$ ,giving us $$ \frac{h}{\cos^2\theta} + \frac{k}{\sin^2\theta}=1 $$ from here we can apply AM-GM inequality , yielding $$hk\leq \sin^22\theta/16$$

Making the maximum required value to be $1/16$, This solves first part of the question.

But now because $P$ only lies on curve $xy=1/16$ at one point $(1/4,1/4)$, We cannot use this function ($y=x/16$) to find the area of the locus of $P$ ( what we need here is the area of the envelope of the line segment $DE$

So my question is how should we visualise and find the area traced by point P?

Comment: It is indeed $1/16$ realized when $C$ is the midpoint of $AB$. In fact, your issue boils down to find a minimum of expression $t(1-t)\lambda(1-\lambda)$ first on $t$, which gives you $1/4$ when $t=1/2$ then on $\lambda$ which gives you the other $1/4$ when $\lambda=1/2$ with final answer $1/4 \times 1/4 = 1/16$. I will maybe expand it into an answer.

Comment: I think you have reasoned for the min of $hk$ part, which seems perfect like that, though my main problem was with the area of the locus part (as P does not 'stick' with the curve xy=1/16) .Correct me if I misunderstood. The given minimum area was $1/6$ just to know.

Comment: You say maximum in your question and minimum in your  comment ? Can I re-phrase your question as: for $C(t,1-t)$ fixed on line $x+y=1$, let $P_t$ the point where the max area is realized. Locus of $P_t$ ?

Comment: Sorry my bad , it is indeed maximum of $hk$ that had been required. I will edit the comment. As for the area , we need the area of the locus of P as traced .

Comment: I have modified my last comment.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I have modified the question a bit to make it clearer. I had solved the first part. I only mention it in the question to tell that I couldn't use it in the second(area) part of the question. I shall not state the area as bieng 'max' or 'min' because it just the area of shaded by the zones where P was. The answer to the first part is $1/16$ (which is seen in the question) while that of the second part is $1/6$ (which is to found yet).Thank you

Comment: As for the rephrasing you mentioned, no that is not the question. The question had two quiet different parts, like I said , the area is not to maxed . $P$  is just a point on the segment $DE$ ,as DE varies it 'shades' out an area, which is what we need

Comment: maybe what is lacking is in point 2 is the "locus of point P **in which the maximum is reached**. I stop there.

Comment: I see your point now. Indeed it probably as you say. That would mean the locus when the Sin inequality above holds right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your parameterization for $C$, line segment $DE$ has the equation

$y = \sin^2(\theta) - \tan^2(\theta) x $

which can written as

$ f(x, y, \theta) = y + \tan^2(\theta) x - \sin^2(\theta)  = 0 $

we want to find the envelope of all such lines segments, and for that we differentiate $f(x, y, \theta)$ with respect to $\theta$ and set that equal to zero.

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} = 2 \tan(\theta) \sec^2(\theta) x - 2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta) x = 0 $

Multiplying through by $\cos^3(\theta) / \sin(\theta) $ results in

$ x = \cos^4(\theta) $

Substituting this into $f(x, y, \theta) = 0 $ gives

$ y = \sin^4(\theta) $

Now, we have to eliminate $\theta$ and obtain a relation between $x$ and $y$ directly.  We note that

$ x + y = \cos^4(\theta) + \sin^4(\theta) = (\cos^2 (\theta) + \sin^2 (\theta))^2 - 2 \cos^2(\theta) \sin^2(\theta) = 1 - 2 \sqrt{x y}$

Hence,

$2 \sqrt{xy} = 1 - x - y $

Squaring both sides,

$ 4 x y = 1 + x^2 + y^2 - 2 x - 2 y + 2 x y $

which simplifies to

$ x^2 + y^2 - 2 x y - 2 x - 2 y + 1 = 0 $

which can be written as

$ (x - y)^2 - 2 (x + y) + 1 = 0 $

Introducing the change of coordinates

$ y' = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (x + y) $

$ x' = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (x - y) $

Then

$ 2 x'^2 - 2 \sqrt{2} y' + 1 = 0 $

Which is the parabola

$y' = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} ( 2 x'^2 + 1 ) $

By sketching this curve, we find that the range for $x'$ is $[-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ] $

The axis of the parabola is $x' = 0$ with corresponds to $ y = x$

The $x$ axis ( $ y = 0 ) $ corresponds to $ y' - x' = 0 $ i.e. $y' = x'$

Now the required area is

$ A = 2 \displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \left( \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} ( 2 x'^2 + 1 ) - x' \right) d x' $

which is straight forward to evaluate

$A = 2 \left[ \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{3} u^3 + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} u  -\dfrac{1}{2} u^2 \right]_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} $

$= 2 \left[ \dfrac{1}{12} + \dfrac{1}{4} - \dfrac{1}{4} \right] = \boxed{\dfrac{1}{6}} $